# Calculating texture coordinates from a grid position

Tags: c#, xna, shader, hlsl

Our game uses a 'block atlas', a grid of square textures which correspond to specific faces of blocks in the game. We're aiming to streamline vertex data memory by storing texture data in the vertex as shorts instead of float2s. Here's our Vertex Definition (XNA, C#):

```
public struct BlockVertex : IVertexType
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Normal;
    /// <summary>
    /// The texture coordinate of this block in reference to the top left corner of an ID's square on the atlas
    /// </summary>
    public short TextureID;
    public short DecalID;


    // Describe the layout of this vertex structure.
    public static readonly VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
    (
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                             VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),

        new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Vector3,
                              VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0),

        new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 6, VertexElementFormat.Short2,
                              VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
    );


    public BlockVertex(Vector3 Position, Vector3 Normal, short TexID)
    {
        this.Position = Position;
        this.Normal = Normal;
        this.TextureID = TexID;
        this.DecalID = TexID;
    }

    // Describe the size of this vertex structure.
    public const int SizeInBytes = (sizeof(float) * 6) + (sizeof(short) * 2);

    VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration
    {
        get { return VertexDeclaration; }
    }
}
```

I have little experience in HLSL, but when I tried to adapt our current shader to use this vertex (as opposed to the old one which stored the Texture and Decal as Vector2 coordinates), I got nothing but transparent blue models, which I believe means that the texture coordinates for the faces are all the same?

Here's the HLSL where I try to interpret the vertex data:

```
int AtlasWidth = 25;
int SquareSize = 32;
float TexturePercent = 0.04; //percent of the entire texture taken up by 1 pixel

[snipped]

struct VSInputTx
{
    float4 Position             : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal               : NORMAL0;
    short2 BlockAndDecalID      : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VSOutputTx
{
    float4 Position     : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal       : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 CameraView   : TEXCOORD1;
    short2 TexCoords    : TEXCOORD2;
    short2 DecalCoords  : TEXCOORD3;
    float FogAmt        : TEXCOORD4;
};

[snipped]

VSOutputTx VSBasicTx( VSInputTx input )
{
    VSOutputTx output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul( input.Position, World );
    float4 viewPosition = mul( worldPosition, View );
    output.Position = mul( viewPosition, Projection );

    output.Normal = mul( input.Normal, World );
    output.CameraView = normalize( CameraPosition - worldPosition );

    output.FogAmt = 1 - saturate((distance(worldPosition,CameraPosition)-FogBegin)/(FogEnd-FogBegin)); //This sets the fog amount (since it needs position data)

    // Convert texture coordinates to short2 from blockID
    // When they transfer to the pixel shader, they will be interpolated
    // per pixel.
    output.TexCoords = short2((short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.x) % (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent), (short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.x) / (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent));
    output.DecalCoords = short2((short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.y) % (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent), (short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.y) / (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent));

    return output;
}
```

I changed nothing else from the original shader which displayed everything fine, but you can see the entire .fx file [here](http://pastebin.com/sMeRVkEJ).

If I could just debug the thing I might be able to get it, but... well, anyways, I think it has to do with my limited knowledge of how shaders work. I imagine my attempt to use integer arithmetic is less than effective. Also, that's a lot of casts, I could believe it if values got forced to 0 somewhere in there. In case I am way off the mark, here is what I aim to achieve:

1. Shader gets a vertex which stores two shorts as well as other data. The shorts represent an ID of a certain corner of a grid of square textures. One is for the block face, the other is for a decal which is drawn over that face.
2. The shader uses these IDs, as well as some constants which define the size of the texture grid (henceforth referred to as "Atlas"), to determine the actual texture coordinate of this particular corner.
3. The X of the texture coordinate is the (ID % AtlasWidth) * TexturePercent, where TexturePercent is a constant which represents the percentage of the entire texture represented by 1 pixel.
4. The Y of the texture coordinate is the (ID / AtlasWidth) * TexturePercent.

How can I go about this?

Update: I got an error at some point "vs_1_1 does not support 8- or 16-bit integers" could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Hey A-Type, I don't know if you know about it or not but you should check out [gamedev.SE]. You may find more resources there on game development than you'll find on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
output.TexCoords = short2((short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.x) % (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent), (short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.x) / (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent));
output.DecalCoords = short2((short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.y) % (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent), (short)(((input.BlockAndDecalID.y) / (AtlasWidth)) * TexturePercent));
```

These two lines contain these following divisions:

`(input.BlockAndDecalID.x) / (AtlasWidth)`

`(input.BlockAndDecalID.y) / (AtlasWidth)`

These are both integer divisions. Integer division cuts off all past the decimal point. I'm assuming AtlasWidth is always greater than each of the coordinates, therefore both of these divisions will always result in 0. If this assumption is incorrect, I'm assuming you still want that decimal data in some way?

You probably want a float division, something that returns a decimal result, so you need to cast at least one (or both) of the operands to a float first, e.g.:

`((float)input.BlockAndDecalID.x) / ((float)AtlasWidth)`

EDIT: I would use [NormalizedShort2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexelementformat.aspx) instead; it scales your value by the max short value (32767), allowing a "decimal-like" use of short values (in other words, "0.5" = 16383). Of course if your intent was just to halve your tex coord data, you can achieve this while still using floating points by using HalfVector2. If you still insist on Short2 you will probably have to scale it like NormalizedShort2 already does before submitting it as a coordinate.

Comment: Actually, integer division is the desired result. The "x" and "y" are deceiving; both of those values are IDs which describe a corner on the grid. The grid is 25 squares wide. If my ID is 58, then ID / GridSize = 2, which is the Y val...

At this point I realize I am a friggin' idiot. I defined a constant for the pixel width of each texture square, but I never used it! I get 2 for my coordinate.Y, which is silly, it should be 2 * 32. With this in mind I will proceed. Thanks for forcing me to think this through more.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was gonna say something looked a little missing there :P I just didn't fully know how you had it set up

Comment: Didn't solve my problems, but I think I'm on the right track now.

Comment: Well, after experimentation, I actually baked the size of the squares into the percentage. 0.04 = 32 / 800 (i.e. 1/25). So, that actually wasn't helpful. Somehow everything's zero-ing out. I'll have to double check my casts and operators...

Comment: Well, again, shorts can't store any decimal information. Let's say in your above example, you get 2 as the y value, and then you multiply that by 0.04, you get 0.08. That will turn out to 0 when you cast.

Comment: I edited my answer, you might want to look at the different vertex format options.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the intention of the data stored in the vertex. If there were an Integer vertex format I would use that. I only want to pass two unrelated integers to the shader, and let the shader process the texture coordinates from those values using a separate algorithm. The purpose is to save vertex size and decrease our memory footprint.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8049/discussion-between-scott-w-and-a-type)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after I tried to create a short in one of the shader functions and faced a compiler error which stated that vs_1_1 doesn't support 8/16-bit integers (why didn't you tell me that before??), I changed the function to look like this:

```
float texX = ((float)((int)input.BlockAndDecalID.x % AtlasWidth) * (float)TexturePercent);
float texY = ((float)((int)input.BlockAndDecalID.x / AtlasWidth) * (float)TexturePercent);
output.TexCoords = float2(texX, texY);
float decX = ((float)((int)input.BlockAndDecalID.y % AtlasWidth) * (float)TexturePercent);
float decY = ((float)((int)input.BlockAndDecalID.y / AtlasWidth) * (float)TexturePercent);
output.DecalCoords = float2(decX, decY);
```

Which seems to work just fine. I'm not sure if it's changing stuff to ints or that (float) cast on the front. I think it might be the float, which means Scott was definitely on to something. My partner wrote this shader somehow to use a short2 as the texture coordinate; how he did that I do not know.

Comment: I didn't want to put too many comments in the above thread, which is why I made it into a chat :). But I was going to explain that you can make the OUTPUT be a float still but the input can be a int if you want. And it seems that is what you've done. Sorry for misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: It's no problem. After further testing I've decided that rounding errors cause problems with this method I don't want to fix, mainly getting the corner number off by 1 for certain IDs. Just reverted the last hour of work, oh well, so it goes...